# Howto write QGIS server WMS GetPrint with 'OR' in filter

Tags: qgis, wms, filter, server

According to the QGIS manual I can include 'OR' in a WMS GetPrint request (https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html#filter)

But I cannot get it to work and I have not yet found an example of what the syntax should look like. Just one of the options I tried:

```
&FILTER=layer1:"attribute" = 3; layer1:OR("attribute2" = 5, "attribute2" = 6)
```

Comment: The documentation you reference says `A space between each word / special character is mandatory.`  have you tried therefore `: OR ("`